# How to fix access rights to run a service on localhost?

Tags: c#, wcf, http.sys

When I try to run my WCF Service on a local host on a console application it shows the following exception for me:

> Could not register URL http://+:8080/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace

I had this service working before on Windows 7. The problem started when I tried to run it on windows 8.1.

Most of the topics I found from the Internet stated that the solution is to register the URL for the current user. I tried that but it didn't work and I didn't find any further steps that I might try.

Comment: "the solution is to register the URL for the current user I tried that but it didn't work" Please show us what you tried [as a edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29479627/edit).

Comment: just run your visual studio as administrator or lunch your .exe as administrator

Comment: @coder1409 thanks for your replay I have read that this is a highly u unrecommended solution is there isn't any other way

Comment: No there is no other way since you don't have right access to open the port , and there is no issues with the solution as far as i am concerned